# How to perform operations in each iteration of UIView animateWithDuration

Tags: ios5, animation, uiview

I am changing the size of a view using animation and I need to change the image of imageview inside that view in every step of the animation. The image depends on the view size that's why I want to do so. I have tried to do that in the `animations:` block, but it seems to be called only once and not for each iteration as I expected.

How can I perform some operations during each iteration of `UIView animateWithDuration:animations:`. Or maybe there is another solution for my problem?

P.S. I have tried to use `completion:` block, but it doesn't solve my problem correctly as I want to achieve smooth change of images.

Comment: Can you resize the image in the same animation block that the view is using?

Answer (score 0):

if i give you simple answer, the answer is no...

but i have an alternative for this make a function which you can call recursively like..

```
-(void)animationRecursive
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.001 animations:^{
        // Here set frame slide different from last frame use incremental variables
        // for x,y,width,height
        //yourImageView.frame = set frame
        //yourImageView.image = set image
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

         if(![yourImage.frame isEqualToString NSStringFromCGRect(yourFinalCGRectAfterAnimation)]
         {
            [self animationRecursive];
         }
    }];

}
```

hope this will help you.............